# $A \mbox{ is an infinite set } \Leftrightarrow \forall n \in \omega, \exists B \subset A \mbox{ such that }B \mbox{ is equipotent to }n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A \mbox{ is an infinite set }  \Leftrightarrow \forall n \in \omega, \exists B \subset A \mbox{ such that }B \mbox{ is equipotent to }n$

$\Rightarrow]$ Let $G=\{n \in \omega: \exists B \subset A \mbox{ such that } B \mbox{ is equipotent to } n\}$

$0 \in G$ because we can take $0 \subset A$ then the function empty is a bijective function from $0$ to $0$.

The problem that I have is prove $n+1 \in G$ when we suppose $n \in G$. If we have that proposition then by induction we finish.

$\Leftarrow ]$ If $A$ is a finite set then $|A| \in \omega$ then exists $B \subset A$ such that $B$ is equipotent to $|A|$, therefore $|B|=||A||=|A|$, so $A=B$. But I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: Exactly what is your definition of *infinite set*?

Comment: $A$ is infinite set if $|A| \geq \omega.|$

Answer (score 1):

If $\omega\le|A|$, then by definition there is an injection $f:\omega\to A$. Given $n\in\omega$, let $B_n=\{f(k):k<n\}$; you can easily check that $|B_n|=n$. Thus, you don’t actually need to use induction at all.

For the other direction, if $A$ is finite, then $|A|=n$ for some $n\in\omega$, and there is a bijection $f:A\to n$, where $n=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$. If $A$ had a subset $B$ such that $|B|=n+1$, there would be a bijection $g:B\to n+1$, and $f\circ g^{-1}$ would then be a bijection from $n+1$ to $n$, which is impossible.